# VS2010 usercontrol & WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, user-controls

We are using usercontrols in c# to have separate classes for features inside a tabm which works perfectly.

Our problem arises, when an usercontrol uses a Service Reference to any Webservice.
The first time dragging the control on the form works. The second time, the designer will show an error:

```
Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'testSR.WebService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.
```

The app.config contains the correct endpoint and it works as long as the calling code is inside the form itself, as soon as we move the code to the usercontrol, we have these problems.

I even tried to put the user control inside another project within the solution referenced it correctly and copied the endpoint/binding configurations from the app.config of the DLL to the EXEs app.config - then also the problem arises again...

It seems that user controls cannot reference webservices, but there should be a solution!?

**EDIT:** From my testing it now seems that user controls can use service references, but the VisualStudio Designer will only work for the first time, after that the programm still works, but the designer shows the error and when I ignore it, the designer removes the user control from the form. As long as I do not touch the containing form, the usercontrol is editable and working fine ...

Comment: Winforms, webforms, wpf, silverlight? They all have "user controls".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are working with winforms. have a clear separation between UI and WCF and avoid this and other issues by making the usercontrol not to call wcf directly but call an intermediate class library which calls the service layer for you. In this way the WCF will be called by such class library and your UI will be isolated.

Actually thinking about this problem you are describing, are you requiring WCF connectivity at design time as well? if so you shoul probably avoid it by checking if running at design time in which case do nothing. removing the dependency and having your UI independent from Service References is anyway surely a good idea.

Comment: I followed your advice and created a library. Interestingly it works fine, when I use WCF calls in static methods, when creating objects, I get the same error (binary works, but designer makes problem)

Answer (score 1):

Only four years late, but I actually found a fix to the WCF issue when instantiating the service in the usercontrol.

1. As @DavidePiras stated, make a service class library and reference the binary .dll. (Call the .dll, `Worker` in this case for my answer)
2. In your user control, rather than instantiating the Worker class in the constructor, make a new method, call it `LoadWorker` in this case.

..

```
private Worker worker;

public CustomUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public void LoadWorker()
{
    worker = new Worker();
}
```

--

3. In your form where you are calling this userControl, but can't see it, then either in another method or in the constructor for the form, call `usercontrol.LoadWorker()`.

--

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent()
    customUserControl.LoadWorker();
}
```

An extra step I took from here was to close all open windows/files and do a `Build Solution`. Then reopen the form that the designer was failing on and it should be good to go.

**Cause?**
The form that worked at runtime versus what you saw in the designer window in VS20xx has to deal with what is instantiated at the runtime versus what occurs when the designer window is loading your user control. I don't know the fine details or the terminology to necessarily describe it, but that is what is causing it. I have found that throwing the loading of the WCF service into a separate method to be the easiest solution.

I hope it helps anyone else who runs by this answer now.