# ServiceReference & User Control & Winform

Tags: c#, service-reference

I have the same issue reported on https://stackoverflow.com/a/38013786/9619666
but the answer is not working. 
My user control uses a service reference and when i try do include on a winform it comes with a endpoint error. but when I add the service after including de usercontrol to the form it works, but when i open in the design it removes de user control. can anyone help? detailed please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS2010 usercontrol & WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823940/vs2010-usercontrol-wcf)

Comment: You have to ensure that dangerous code inside the constructor or Load event handler cannot run while the control is being used at design-time.  http://dotnetfacts.blogspot.com/2009/01/identifying-run-time-and-design-mode.html